# Prove that $b^r =\sup B(r)$ when $r$ is rational.

Tags: real-analysis

The information provided for this problem is:
Fix $b>1$ and suppose we only have defined $b^r$ where $r$ is rational by $b^r=(b^m)^{1/n}$ whenever $r=m/n$.

The actual problem states: If $x$ is real, define $B(x)$ to be the set of all numbers $b^t$ where $t$ is rational and $t$ is less than or equal to $x$. Prove that $b^r=\sup B(r)$ when $r$ is rational.

Comment: What else do you know? If you know that $x\mapsto b^x$ is an increasing function, then it's just $\sup (\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,b^r])$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $t=\frac{p}{q}$ and $r=\frac{m}{n}$, where $m,n,p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $n,q>0$.

If we can show that $t\leq r\implies b^t\leq b^r$ ($t,r\in\mathbb{Q}$), then $b^r$ will be an upper bound for the set $B(r)$, and it will also be a least upper bound, because $b^r\in B(r)$.

Note that

\begin{align*}
t&\leq r \\
\implies\frac{p}{q}&\leq\frac{m}{n} \\
\implies pn&\leq mq \\
\implies 0&\leq mq-pn
\end{align*}

Consider $b^{mq-pn}$. Since $mq-pn\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$, it is either 1 (when $mq-pn=0$), or $b$ multiplied by itself $mq-pn$ times (when $mq-pn\geq1$). It follows inductively from the properties of a field that in the latter case:

$$\underbrace{b\cdot b\cdots b}_{mq-pn\text{ times}}>\underbrace{1\cdot1\cdots1}_{mq-pn\text{ times}}=1.$$

Therefore, $b^{mq-pn}\geq1\implies b^{mq}\geq b^{pn}$. Now we want to be able to take the $nq$th root across the inequality, but we need to prove something first:

**Lemma**: If $c\leq d$, and $x\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, then $c^{1/x}\leq d^{1/x}$.

**Proof**: Suppose that $c^{1/x}>d^{1/x}$. Then

$$\underbrace{c^{1/x}\cdot c^{1/x}\cdots c^{1/x}}_{x\text{ times}} > \underbrace{d^{1/x}\cdot d^{1/x}\cdots d^{1/x}}_{x\text{ times}}\implies c>d$$

this is a contradiction. So $c^{1/x}\leq d^{1/x}$.

Applying this to our previous inequality, we get:

\begin{align*}
b^{mq}&\geq b^{np} \\
\implies (b^{mq})^{1/(nq)} &\geq (b^{np})^{1/(nq)} \\
\implies b^{m/n} &\geq b^{p/q} \\
\implies b^r &\geq b^t
\end{align*}

as desired.