# How to define $b^x = \sup B(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ given that $b^r = \sup B(r)$ has been proven for $r \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, rational-numbers

> Fix $b > 1$. If $x$ is real, define $B(x)$ to be the set of all numbers $b^t$, where $t$ is rational and $t \le x$. Prove that $b^r = \sup B(r)$ when $r$ is rational. Hence it makes sense to define $b^x = \sup B(x)$ for every real $x$.

The first part of the question is rather easy and has been proven by [an answer to a previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/949066/1103495). Now I am wondering whether the second half, defining $b^x$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, needs to be rigorously proven, and if so, how.

My intuition tells me for each $x$, $b^x$ can be defined as $\sup B(r)$ where $r$ is the greatest rational smaller than $x$. I am unsure about how to communicate this intuition mathematically (given it is correct).

Comment: $b^x$ is being defined as $\sup B(x)$. There is nothing to prove.

Comment: Got it. However, it is still not entirely clear to me what is the connection between proving $b^r = \sup B(r)$ for $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ and saying that it makes sense to define $b^x$ as $\sup B(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: We have already defined $b^r$ for $r = m/n \in \mathbf{Q}$ as $(b^m)^{1/n}$. We would now like to extend our definition for exponentiation to include all real numbers as powers, by setting $b^x = \sup B(x)$ for $x \in \mathbf{R}$. The point of this exercise is to show that this new definition agrees with the old definition for rational powers.